# reason behind the default keyword for ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am following along in a React tutorial right now that currently uses ES6. I am new to the ES6 and I have been seeing the default keyword used quite often when it comes to exporting names from modules. I have been trying to comprehend what the reasoning behind the default word is, but have not found an answer I can comprehend yet.

Here is an example:

```js
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink>
      {" | "}
      <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">About</Link>
      {" | "}
      <Link to ="/course" activeClassName="active">Courses</Link>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Thank you in advance and let me know if I am not clear on anything.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because you can export many variables  from the same file , `default` is used only once in the whole file  to let you import this default variable outside without using brackets `{}`:

```
export default Header;
```

let you to import it :

```
import Header from './Header.jsx';
```

---

```
export {Header};
```

let you to import it :

```
import {Header} from './Header.jsx';
```

Comment: Main reason is to allow you to import with the name of your choice, since it is default export, it can be imported with alias name

Comment: Just as feedback to the wonderful folks working on ES6, the naming of `default` was rather inconvenient for porting existing code from ES5..ah well